# Vim - how to change variables, defined by plugins?

Tags: variables, vim, plugins

I want to use vim module PDV (PHP Documentator for Vim), this module provides following variables (from pdv.vim):

```
" Default values
let g:pdv_cfg_Type = "mixed"
let g:pdv_cfg_Package = ""
let g:pdv_cfg_Version = "$id$"
let g:pdv_cfg_Author = "Tobias Schlitt <toby@php.net>"
let g:pdv_cfg_Copyright = "1997-2005 The PHP Group"
let g:pdv_cfg_License = "PHP Version 3.0 {@link http://www.php.net/license/3_0.txt}"
```

And I want to change them, but I can't do that. Please, explain, how can I change this variables in my vimrc file?

Comment: Well, you do exactly what you did here: you paste them in your `vimrc`. And you change the values.

Comment: @romainl this variant doesn't work at all, that's why i added question to stackoverflow

Comment: Instead of the plugin's issue tracker? What a strange idea…

Comment: @romainl, I mean that it's my problem, not plugin, because variables work, but I can't change them myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was bug in old version of PDV (from vim-scripts.org), but it already fixed in new version